# Convert character matrix into numeric matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 7 by 31 character matrix called `extra4` and its structure looks like this:

```
> str(extra4)
 chr [1:7, 1:31] "36.88  " " 45.48  " " 52.46  " " 111.31 " " 138.45 " " 121.09 " " 122.62" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "1990" "1991" "1992" "1993" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:31] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

After reading similar questions in SO I've tried the following but I've failed:

```
>matrix(as.numeric(unlist(extra4)),nrow=nrow(extra4))
Warning message:
In matrix(as.numeric(unlist(extra4)), nrow = nrow(extra4)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

and also I've tried

```
> class(extra4)<-"numeric"
Warning message:
In class(extra4) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion

> extra4<-apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric)
Warning messages:
1: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
7: In apply(extra4, 1, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion

> extra4<-apply(extra4, 2, as.numeric)
There were 31 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I've also tried changing the matrix to data frame and then doing `sapply(extra4, as.numeric)` but this did not work either, and I've also tried writing the data as csv but somehow the output ends up including non-numeric characters.

It's strange because especially after doing the above, only some of the numbers are turned to numeric values. However, I'm sure that all elements are character, because when I compare those which are saved and those which are not, I get

```
> str(extra4[1,1])
 chr "36.88  "
> str(extra4[1,2])
 chr " 19.11  "
```

I'm also adding the following to show my data in more detail:

```
extra4 <- matrix(
  c(
    "36.88  ", " 45.48  ", " 52.46  ", " 111.31 ", " 138.45 ",
    " 121.09 ", " 122.62", " 19.11  ", " 27.97  ", " 37.14  ", " 47.68  ",
    " 60.78  ", " 35.84  ", " 38.64", " 56.21  ", " 74.94  ", " 92.3   ",
    " 118.62 ", " 138.13 ", " 104.65 ", " 113.98", " 30.48  ", " 51.54  ",
    " 61.57  ", " 99.87  ", " 80.9   ", " 84.97  ", " 99.34", "20.16  ",
    " 24.76  ", " 27.76  ", " 37.53  ", " 50.53  ", " 28.8   ", " 25.06",
    " 87.73  ", " 98.68  ", " 119.95 ", " 150.74 ", " 214.35 ", " 118.5  ",
    " 129.19", " 32.36  ", " 36.52  ", " 42.67  ", " 56.55  ", " 89.22  ",
    " 49.97  ", " 50.62", "35.09  ", " 40.77  ", " 48.43  ", " 82.61  ",
    " 120.1  ", " 72.43  ", " 76.69", " 47.21  ", " 67.25  ", " 78.62  ",
    " 66.64  ", " 83.78  ", " 127.79 ", " 154.11", " 86.1   ", " 127.59 ",
    " 164.43 ", " 249.32 ", " 312.01 ", " 272.09 ", " 265.68", " 83.75  ",
    " 118.41 ", " 171.52 ", " 229.27 ", " 241.63 ", " 201    ", " 213.01",
    " 36.63  ", " 52.1   ", " 66.03  ", " 101.38 ", " 126.71 ", " 95.46  ",
    " 110.03", " 57.5   ", " 75.72  ", " 101.31 ", " 147.5  ", " 171.01 ",
    " 148.66 ", " 167.93", " 29.56  ", " 38.37  ", " 48.8   ", " 65.5   ",
    " 84.77  ", " 75.2   ", " 81.27", " 77.28  ", " 93.7   ", " 119.62 ",
    " 247    ", " 301.76 ", " 222.52 ", " 244.46", " 45.6   ", " 54.32  ",
    " 87.81  ", " 132.93 ", " 163.62 ", " 152.99 ", " 170.85", " 27.13  ",
    " 36.96  ", " 48.94  ", " 80.01  ", " 124.07 ", " 93.49  ", " 105.57",
    " 54.55  ", " 85.93  ", " 102.3  ", " 122.7  ", " 168.36 ", " 151.79 ",
    " 169.65", " 86.19  ", " 121.82 ", " 191.7  ", " 247.75 ", " 260.23 ",
    " 196.48 ", " 243.06", "47.35  ", " 60.63  ", " 76.4   ", " 93.04  ",
    " 102.13 ", " 98.29  ", " 86.27", " 10.93  ", " 13.33  ", " 16.82  ",
    " 18.2   ", " 23.48  ", " 16.52  ", " 16.19", "   NA   ", "  NA    ",
    "   NA   ", "  NA    ", " 69.46  ", " 54.22  ", " 60.16", " 60.93  ",
    " 89.86  ", " 141.85 ", " 207.9  ", " 182.79 ", " 159.1  ", " 159.46",
    " 15.37  ", " 18.48  ", " 24.33  ", " 38.37  ", " 45.87  ", " 34.86  ",
    " 31.96", " 34.05  ", " 40.1   ", " 55.02  ", " 58.31  ", " 86.89  ",
    " 65.68  ", " 65.68", "1.51   ", " 0.93   ", " 1      ", " 1.78   ",
    " 2.8    ", " 1.56   ", " 1.41", " 27.15  ", " 31.37  ", " 39.46  ",
    " 40.33  ", " 61.86  ", " 45.18  ", " 57.71", " 14.74  ", " 16.3   ",
    " 25.06  ", " 31.74  ", " 37.39  ", " 27.18  ", " 30.49", " 3.59   ",
    " 4.86   ", " 5.67   ", " 6.36   ", " 7.6    ", " 4.8    ", " 5.5",
    "4.73   ", " 5.68   ", " 7.3    ", " 8.53   ", " 11.03  ", " 8.44   ",
    " 9.84", "16.76  ", " 24.83  ", " 32.66  ", " 46.22  ", " 48.01  ",
    " 43.44  ", " 48.29"
  ),
  nrow = 7L,
  ncol = 31L,
  dimnames = list(
    c("1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996"),
    c(
      "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",
      "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23",
      "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"
    )
  )
)
```

`sessionInfo()` gave the following:

```
    > sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gdata_2.13.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] gtools_2.7.1 tools_3.0.0
```

Comment: what did you expect `sapply(extra4, as.numeric())` to do?

Comment: to turn all vectors in extra4 into numeric?

Comment: I don't know anything about how the extra white spaces appeared in your data in the first place, or if you at some stage have used `read.table` to read 'corrupt' data. Anyway, I just wish to remind you about the `strip.white` argument in `read.table`.

Comment: @Henrik I'll look into that, thank you. I don't understand either, because I looked back at the excel file and it looks fine. I used read.xls.

Comment: I think you can use the `read.table` arguments in `read.xls`. And: what you see, is **not** what you get in Excel files...

Comment: @Henrik I just found out I can't use strip.white in read.xls...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There isn't really a problem here at all, not with most options I tried. You are getting **Warnings** but these pertain to the `"NA"` strings, which because they aren't `NA` nor a number stored in a string, R doesn't know what to do with them and changes these to `NA`. This is all the warning is telling you. Hence

```
apply(extra4, 2, as.numeric)
sapply(extra4, as.numeric)
class(extra4) <- "numeric"
storage.mode(extra4) <- "numeric"
```

all work and all warn about the "  NA  " values (or variants thereof) in column 22 of `extra4`:

```
Warning message:
In storage.mode(m) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

but these are just warnings and in this case can be ignored. If they trouble you, you could wrap the call in `suppressWarnings()`

```
> suppressWarnings(storage.mode(m) <- "numeric")
```

but that is dangerous as it will stop all warnings, not just the one about the `NA`s.

Comment: Thank you! I think what you mention is the problem when converting the character. However I get a similar error "Warning message:
In storage.mode(extra4) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion", and then I get a matrix full of NAs even after doing sub() and storage.mode().

Comment: @Rusuer9000 Then there is something else about your data that we cannot see from the snippet you showed - I read into R the 7 values you do show and the code I showed works. Can you edit your question and include the output from `dput(extra4)`? That way we can recreate exactly the object you have?

Comment: I added the 'dput(extra4)'. I think the problem is occurring because the spaces for each element is not the same across all elements. For instance some can be "4 " but some can be "5     ".

Comment: @Rusuer9000 Thanks, you want `gsub()` not `sub()`. Will update the answer

Comment: Both `sub` and `gsub` are unnecessary here. The command `storage.mode(m) <- "numeric"` is sufficient.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Good catch. Want to add that as an answer so I can delete mine?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein OK, but only if you are happy with that?!

Comment: Of course, your solution works (independent of the `sub`/`gsub`).

Comment: But actually storage.mod2() gives the same result as apply() and so forth: > storage.mode(extra4) <- "numeric"   ## make numeric
Warning message:
In storage.mode(extra4) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @Rusuer9000 This warning is no problem. It is because the string `"NA"` was transformed to numeric `NA`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein But almost all of the elements have turned into NAs. I get the same result I get after doing apply().

Comment: @Rusuer9000 The `storage.mode` solution works with the object you provided (at least on my system).

Comment: @Rusuer9000 The problem, if there is one, is that these generated warnings and all options worked. I have changed my answer with a longer explanation of what is going on.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Should I post the RData I'm using? I understand what you're saying but in the end I end up with a matrix full of NAs and that's just waste of valuable data.

Comment: @Rusuer9000 The `dput()` should have been fine. Can you add the output from `sessionInfo()` now please (in your question).

Comment: @GavinSimpson I added the sessionInfo().

Comment: @Rusuer9000 OK, try the code in a new R session without loading any packages. In your new, clean session do `extra4 <- structure(....` where the `structure(....` part is pasted in from this question (the output from `dput()` that you pasted into your question. Then try the solutions shown above. That will help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: @GavinSimpson It worked! Thank you so much! Do you think the problem was caused because of the gdata package?

Comment: @Rusuer9000 No, I just tried and there wasn't an issue. I have R 3.0.2 though and newer **gtools**, so that could be issue.

Answer (score 18):

```
m <- matrix(data = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

class(m) <- "numeric"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is a big brain move, Matheus. 
@Tyler2P every R object has a class which affects how it behaves. What this does is change the class of the object without having to recompute anything. By doing this the representation shifts from character to numeric. It's brilliant.

Comment: Wow, I love the simplicity of this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can just apply:

```
data.matrix(frame, rownames.force = NA)
```

Here more info: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.matrix.html

Comment: I like the direct nature of this solution!

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a character matrix m, i.e.

```
m <- matrix(data = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
```

Simply mapply as.numeric, i.e.

```
m <- mapply(m, FUN=as.numeric)
```

And use the data to reconstruct the matrix with the same dimensions as the original m matrix, i.e.

```
m <- matrix(data=m, ncol=2, nrow=3)
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to use `mapply` unless you actually have multiple arguments.

Comment: What are the downsides @C8H10N4O2? I think my solution could be more elegant TBH

Comment: Just use `sapply` because your function has a single argument. `mapply` M is for multiple arguments. So you just took an existing answer and used the wrong function for it. -1

Comment: My mistake, I thought the m was for matrix, akin to the l in lapply (ie. for list). FYI I didn't take my answer from the previous answer, I just thought mapply was the better function for it. Are there performance issues with using mapply for single argument situations? Does it add unnecessary computation complexity or just a single iteration? Do you know if there is any real difference, i.e. why is it bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest base R method would be:

```
m <- matrix(data = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

m <- apply(m, 2 ,as.numeric)
```