# How to convert a character matrix to numeric without affecting row/col-names

Tags: r

I am currently trying to run a PCA on some log2cpm data from RNA-expression. I have done the following preprocessing of data:

- Upload my expression dataset
- Filtered out genes based on a selection of genes(score list) that I want to investigate further.

Set dataset for control and treatment:

```
dataset <- read.table("log2cpm.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE, row.names =  NULL) %>% na.omit()#dataset
        dataset <- dataset[!duplicated(dataset$hgnc_symbol), ]
        row.names(dataset) <- dataset$hgnc_symbol
        #Set genedabase
        gene_DB <- read.table("TableS1.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)  #selection
        gene_DB <- gene_DB[!duplicated(gene_DB$Symbol), ]
        row.names(gene_DB) <- gene_DB$Symbol
```

I then filtered the genes:

```
#Filter genes from dataset based on imported database
dataset_filtered <- dataset %>% filter(hgnc_symbol %in% gene_DB$Symbol)
```

Further I transposed(flipped) the dataframe and converted it into a matrix:

```
    data_tsc <- t(as.matrix(dataset_filtered))
colnames(data_tsc) <- c(data_tsc[2,1:ncol(data_tsc)])
data_tsc <- data_tsc[c(-1,-2),]
```

You can see in the code that I always try to keep the rownames(sample) and col_names(genes), so that I can make some sense out of the PCA and data when its processed, and keep track of the 300+ genes.

This however does not work when I run the matrix (data_tsc) through PCA analysis:

```
    #Run PCA####
pca <- prcomp(data_tsc[,c(1:ncol(data_tsc))], center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
```

This returns:

> Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

After vigorous googling I identified the problem: `as.matrix` and `t()` done previously turn the numeric values into `chr`.

I have tried to correct this numerous times with functions like: apply, lapply, as.numeric etc. etc etc. I have been googling a ton, and all the proposed solutions, either messes up my rows and cols, or they disrupt the whole dataset.

So is there an easy and quick solution to turning the chr values into numeric, while still sparing my row and cols? It would much appreciated :D

Ps. I am just learning coding, but striking into some issues.

**CHANGES:**

*NelsonGon asked me to provide this input:*

```
dput(head(data_tsc))
```

*Which returned*

```
structure(c("4,891962697", "4,807689723", "5,07457417", "5,086369154", 
"4,914961379", "4,83431453", "6,583923027", "6,482957338", "6,587420199", 
"6,532262901", "6,438933039", "6,448834899", "2,832721409", "2,881398092", 
"2,389231753", "2,780670224", "2,417835957", "2,761576388", "7,494008371", 
"7,58143903", "7,62969704", "7,579694323", "7,438227488", "7,513190279", 
"6,257073157", "6,351044394", "6,313216639", "6,597298125", "6,112566161", 
"6,315617767", "6,822914122", "6,660904066", "6,925653718", "7,379973187", 
"6,804033651", "6,443382931", "5,271577287", "5,510134745", "5,418971124", 
"5,551120518", "5,302474278", "5,552416478", "5,165993558", "5,030291607", 
"5,145076323", "4,905049925", "5,202651513", "5,250135996", "2,827019018", 
"2,626020468", "2,702723667", "2,575260635", "2,30347029", "2,449794083", 
"5,866824758", "5,881522359", "5,913145862", "5,922174742", "5,869024665", 
"5,896680873"), .Dim = c(6L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(c("LIG_UT_1", 
"LIG_UT_2", "LIG_UT_3", "LIG_UT_4", "LIG_UT_5", "LIG_UT_6"), 
    c("ACVR1", "ADAM17", "AGER", "AKT1", "ANPEP", "ANXA1", "AR", 
    "ATM", "AURKA", "AXIN1")))
```

**Changes after second suggestion**:
I changed this in read.table()

```
dataset <- read.table("log2cpm.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE, row.names =  NULL, dec = ",")
```

Specifing dec = ","

This gave the following output in dput:

```
structure(c(" 4.8919627", " 4.8076897", " 5.0745742", " 5.0863692",
```

" 4.9149614", " 4.8343145", " 6.5839230", " 6.4829573", " 6.5874202", 
" 6.5322629", " 6.4389330", " 6.4488349", " 2.8327214", " 2.8813981", 
" 2.3892318", " 2.7806702", " 2.4178360", " 2.7615764", " 7.4940084", 
" 7.5814390", " 7.6296970", " 7.5796943", " 7.4382275", " 7.5131903", 
" 6.2570732", " 6.3510444", " 6.3132166", " 6.5972981", " 6.1125662", 
" 6.3156178", " 6.8229141", " 6.6609041", " 6.9256537", " 7.3799732", 
" 6.8040337", " 6.4433829", " 5.2715773", " 5.5101347", " 5.4189711", 
" 5.5511205", " 5.3024743", " 5.5524165", " 5.1659936", " 5.0302916", 
" 5.1450763", " 4.9050499", " 5.2026515", " 5.2501360", " 2.8270190", 
" 2.6260205", " 2.7027237", " 2.5752606", " 2.3034703", " 2.4497941", 
" 5.8668248", " 5.8815224", " 5.9131459", " 5.9221747", " 5.8690247", 
" 5.8966809"), .Dim = c(6L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(c("LIG_UT_1", 
"LIG_UT_2", "LIG_UT_3", "LIG_UT_4", "LIG_UT_5", "LIG_UT_6"), 
    c("ACVR1", "ADAM17", "AGER", "AKT1", "ANPEP", "ANXA1", "AR", 
    "ATM", "AURKA", "AXIN1")))

**Solution**

```
Based on Adams suggestion prrevious suggestion to add dec = "," in read.table, and to afterwards use use the following code:

    dataset_numeric <- apply(data_tsc, 2, as.numeric)
rownames(data_numeric) <- rownames(data_tsc)
colMeans(data_tsc)
```

I managed to turn the the character values to numeric, while still keeping row and colulms. PCA worked, and:

```
is.numeric(dataset_numeric)
```

[1] TRUE

Thank you for all for helping me out, I was about to tear my hair off in frustration.

Comment: You can use `dput(head(dataset_name))` to provide sample data for better reproducibility.

Comment: Ok, I read quickly about this dput function. So if I apply this:
dput(head(data_tsc)) I will get some metadata about row/col names, so how do I like this up to the numeric converted dataset?

Comment: Oh no! This is just to add data to the question not solve it. Copy and paste its output to the question.

Comment: Hey, look at changes. I have added what you suggested :)

Comment: Is it too long? You need to just copy and paste it as is(Don't manipulate it). It's the only(best) way for people to have access to your data.

Comment: Yeah,  its waaay too long. I added 10x10  of dput(), the still problems still arise though - so its a good insight :) Take a look in changes

Comment: Is the comma equivalent to a decimal (e.g., euro vs US notation)? That might be your problem. There is a an option `dec` in `read.table` to address that.

Comment: Hey,
I got this data from someone in my group with log2cpm in a excel sheet. It should be (dots), right? But it was commas in the excel sheet, could this be the problem? I have tried to correct for this, but excel turns the data into date format when I tinker with it, and honestly I dont want to mess to much around in excel because you never know what it does to your data :)

Comment: The convention would be to not add the answer into the original question. Keep the question as clean and clear as you can, and then accept an answer if that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that the decimal is a comma instead of a period. Try first converting that.

```
dataset_numeric <- sub(",",".",dataset)
```

Once that is done, this should be fairly simple. If starting from here, this may be a duplicate of the following with the added requirement of row names.

[Convert character matrix into numeric matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791877/convert-character-matrix-into-numeric-matrix)

So in this case you can modify slightly:

```
dataset_numeric <- apply(dataset_numeric, 2, as.numeric)
rownames(dataset_numeric) <- rownames(dataset)
```

Or choose this option:

```
class(dataset_numeric) <- "numeric"
```

To test:

```
prcomp(dataset_numeric, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Runs without an error:

```
Standard deviations (1, .., p=6):
[1] 2.191373e+00 1.464462e+00 1.331818e+00 1.002092e+00 5.246949e-01 3.755055e-15

Rotation (n x k) = (10 x 6):
               PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5         PC6
ACVR1  -0.33509491 -0.32378624  0.35207791  0.04650037 -0.22465986 -0.07403592
ADAM17 -0.26169241 -0.47259488 -0.30394898 -0.13763357 -0.18328981  0.41562880
AGER   -0.07354562  0.38073508 -0.56645061  0.26681868 -0.28597500  0.12602119
AKT1   -0.37111066  0.01674254 -0.07923664 -0.48941844  0.56009962  0.31877982
ANPEP  -0.41234145  0.25398752 -0.06276181  0.12397346 -0.28744359  0.12200886
ANXA1  -0.34908735 -0.20718967  0.18610579  0.51004989 -0.01539492  0.28629143
AR     -0.23808868  0.54584757  0.08481153 -0.27218135 -0.07711181  0.16714943
ATM     0.37104240 -0.14079095  0.04995052 -0.44945864 -0.56884559  0.33723134
AURKA  -0.20262305 -0.29758992 -0.57407802 -0.16727601 -0.03025329 -0.51762461
AXIN1  -0.38573848  0.11317416  0.28050560 -0.29761514 -0.32731009 -0.44477115
```

Comment: Hey, please see the changes part 2 in the main question above :)

Comment: That should take care of the first line `sub()`. Does the rest not work for you still?

Comment: Hey, it worked! Thank you alot. See Solution in original question :)

Comment: Ps. btw. I ticked of that fly legg as approved answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `dplyr::mutate` in r to solve this:
`mat.char %>% data.frame() %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric)) %>% as.matrix() -> mat.num`