# How to create a side by side barplot in R? (Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator)

Tags: r, error-handling, bar-chart, col

I have a matrix of type

```
    1    2    3    4    5   
A " 9" "27" " 0" "46" "50"
B "46" "34" "27" "22" " 3"
```

which I am trying to create a barplot of with

```
barplot(df, beside=TRUE)
```

but I am getting an error message

```
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

and I don't what is going wrong. I want the barplot to be a side by side barplot that goes from 1-5 like the column names and there's two bars (A and B) for each number side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are stored as characters, that's why you get the `non-numeric argument` error. Try this:

```
df <- matrix(c("1","2","3","4"), ncol = 2) #use your own data, just to make it reproducible

df <- apply(df,1, as.numeric)

barplot(df, beside=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi! What is the a in "apply(a,1, as.numeric)"?

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo, should be `df`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- matrix(c("9", "27", "0", "46", "50", "46", "34", "27", "22", "3"), nrow = 2, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("A", "B"),
                           c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))) 
class(df) <- "numeric"

barplot(df, beside=TRUE)
```

And here is a reference to an answer outlining options for converting from character to numeric matrix: [Convert character matrix into numeric matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791877/convert-character-matrix-into-numeric-matrix)

[image: Plot]