# How can I convert time duration written as' in words (Xhours Xminutes) to numbers using R?

Tags: r, time

I am using data that has times written as words...

```
time <- c('1 hour 1 minute', '2 hours 3 minutes', '45 minutes')
```

I would like to convert these times to the following format...

```
time <- c(61,123,45)
```

I was wondering if anyone had a straightforward method for this using r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
hours <- stringr::str_extract_all(time, "[0-9]+(?=\\s*hour)")
hours <- replace(hours, sapply(hours, Negate(length)), "0")
hours <- as.integer(unlist(hours))
hours
# [1] 1 2 0
minutes <- stringr::str_extract_all(time, "[0-9]+(?=\\s*minute)")
minutes <- replace(minutes, sapply(minutes, Negate(length)), "0")
minutes <- as.integer(unlist(minutes))
minutes
# [1]  1  3 45
hours*60 + minutes
# [1]  61 123  45
```

Or a little more compactly:

```r
mtx <- cbind(
  stringr::str_extract_all(time, "[0-9]+(?=\\s*hour)", TRUE), 
  stringr::str_extract_all(time, "[0-9]+(?=\\s*minute)", TRUE))
storage.mode(mtx) <- "numeric"
mtx[is.na(mtx)] <- 0
mtx
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    0   45
60 * mtx[,1] + mtx[,2]
# [1]  61 123  45

### or
mtx %*% c(60, 1)
#      [,1]
# [1,]   61
# [2,]  123
# [3,]   45
```

(Use of `storage.mode` suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/20791975)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can substitute digit-space-"hour(s)" with "+digit*60" and substitute digit-"minute(s)" with "+digit" and evaluate the expression.

```
library(tidyverse) #or stringr and purrr

time %>% 
  str_replace('(\\d+) hour(s)?', '+\\1*60') %>% 
  str_replace('(\\d+) minute(s)?', '+\\1') %>% 
  map_dbl(~ eval(parse(text = .)))

# [1]  61 123  45
```

Comment: I think anybody who submits answers using `eval(parse(...))` should have to maintain that code in perpetuity ;-)

Comment: Fair enough. Your answer is more robust for sure. On the other hand, if these are human generated strings and the format isn't guaranteed, parsing them dependably will be a headache no matter what. Some examples that both our answers fail at: "one hour" "1 hour 2 mins". The second one mine fails with an error while yours silently gives the wrong answer ;)

Comment: So true, please realize my comment was mostly in jest, I'm not trying to say "mine is better". My biggest concern with `eval` would be if/when either (a) R-injection is a thing, perhaps [*Little `R`obbie Tables*](https://xkcd.com/327/) will be the next big thing; and/or (b) troubleshooting `eval`ed code can be a real pain. Yours is a novel approach, either way. (We're both in the land of [regex](https://xkcd.com/1171/) regardless.)

Comment: Wasn't even thinking about security concerns, good point

Comment: It isn't a concern until it is :-) Set `time <- "rm(list=ls())"` and then ... don't run your code :-P

Answer (score 0):

Try with you own function:

```
mtime = function(tx){
  utx = unlist(strsplit(tx,split=" ",perl=T))
  if (length(utx)==4) {
    sum(as.numeric(utx[c(1,3)])*c(60,1))
  } else as.numeric(utx[c(1)]) 
}

stime = sapply(time,mtime)

# 1 hour 1 minute 2 hours 3 minutes        45 minutes 
#              61               123                45
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example the next works:

```
time <- sapply(sub("minutes*","*1",sub("hours*","*60 +",time)),function(x) eval(parse(text=x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
time
```