In R, how do you change the class of data in a matrix?
Say you have a matrix of logical values of size 6x4:
set.seed(4)
mat <- matrix(sample(c(T, F), 24, replace = T), ncol = 4)
mat

#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

How would you coerce this to be a matrix of data of a different class? For example, if you want it to be integers, such that FALSE is coerced to 0 and TRUE is coerced to 1, you might try as.integer:
as.integer(mat)
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1

That doesn't work as it also turns the matrix into a 1-dimensional vector. You might then rebuild a matrix of the same size, but this seems like an inelegant or indirect approach. Can you coerce the data in the matrix into another class without having to rebuild the matrix?
matrix(as.integer(mat), ncol = ncol(mat))

     # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    1
# [5,]    1    1    0    1
# [6,]    0    0    1    1


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791877/convert-character-matrix-into-numeric-matrix. We can use class(mat) <- "character" or class(mat) <- "integer" etc.

You can use storage.mode <-:

Get or set the ‘mode’ (a kind of ‘type’), or the storage mode of an R object.

storage.mode(mat) <- "integer"
storage.mode(mat) <- "numeric"
storage.mode(mat) <- "character"

(however, trying to convert to character and then back to logical will fail ...)

Any differences between changing storage.mode and class?

The class of a matrix is matrix while the mode of a matrix is the class of the data in the matrix. The class of a data.frame is data.frame while its mode is list. I don't quite understand the difference but I think mode is a limited set of data types available in R, while class can be user defined?

The easiest way is:
> mat*1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1
[5,]    1    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1


What if you wanted it to be a character?

class(mat) <- "character"

That's the solution! Thanks
